# Linear equations modulo different prime through CRT

Tags: finite-fields, chinese-remainder-theorem

Given prime $p$ and equations 
$$a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=d_1\bmod p \\
a_2x+b_2y+c_2z=d_2\bmod p \\
a_3x+b_3y+c_3z=d_3\bmod p$$

where $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i\in\Bbb Z_p$, we can solve for $x,y,z\in\Bbb Z_p$.

Now suppose given primes $p_1,p_2,p_3$ and equations 
$$a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=d_1\bmod p_1\\
a_2x+b_2y+c_2z=d_2\bmod p_2\\
a_3x+b_3y+c_3z=d_3\bmod p_3$$

where $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i\in\Bbb Z_{p_i}$, can we solve for $x,y,z\in\Bbb Z$ such that each $a_ix+b_iy+c_iz=d_i\bmod p_i$ is satisfied by $x\bmod p_i,y\bmod p_i$ and $z\bmod p_i$?

Assume $p_1p_2,p_2p_3,p_3p_1<x,y,z<p_1p_2p_3$

---

I do not follow Gerry Myerson's comments completely. Could someone elucidate further?

Comment: I like it +1 :) simple but Nice ..

Comment: First you can solve $u\equiv d_1\bmod{p_1}$, $u\equiv d_2\bmod{p_2}$, $u\equiv d_3\bmod{p_3}$. Then let $P$ be the lcm of the $p_i$, and solve $a_1x+b_1y+c_1z\equiv u\bmod P$, $a_2x+b_2y+c_2z\equiv u\bmod P$, $a_3x+b_3y+c_3z\equiv u\bmod P$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson but $a_i\in\Bbb Z_{p_i}$ and not in $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Why don't you try working through an example?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I dont have a clue thats why I am asked

Comment: You don't have a clue how to solve a system $u\equiv d_1\bmod{p_1}$, $u\equiv d_2\bmod{p_2}$, $u\equiv d_3\bmod{p_3}$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson 
I know how to solve for $u$ by CRT... I do not know to solve for $x,y,z$ which is the query since $a_i,b_i,c_i$ are in $\Bbb Z_{p_i}$ not in $\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Could you clarify why each $a_ix+b_iy+c_iz\equiv u\bmod P$?